# Can't add jquery timepicker in mvc razor 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, timepicker

I am trying to add a timepicker in a textbox control (TimeFrom and Timeto model properties) in mvc5 razor view giving it a selector class. I used jquery timepicker and added reference for them.

1. //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js
2. //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css"

But its not showing anything.

My code is given below:

```
    @model MLMS.Library.Models.SaveLibraryUnit

    @{
      Layout = null;
    var dropDownListHelper = new MLMS.Services.Common.DropDownListHelper();
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>Unit Information</legend>

    <div class="row input-gap">
        <div class="five columns">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UNIT_NAME, new { @class = "" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UNIT_NAME, new { @class = "u-full-width" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UNIT_NAME)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-gap">
        <div class="three columns">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VEHICLEID, new { @class = "" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VEHICLEID, dropDownListHelper.GetUnassignedVehicle((Model == null ? 0 : Model.VEHICLEID ?? 0)), "select", new { @class = "u-full-width" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VEHICLEID)
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DATE_DEPLOYED, new { @class = "" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DATE_DEPLOYED, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "u-full-width datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DATE_DEPLOYED)
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model != null && Model.UNITID != 0)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="three columns">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.STATUS, new { @class = "" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.STATUS, MLMS.Common.UtilityHelper.ActiveInactiveStatus(@Model.StatusEnum), new { @class = "u-full-width" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.STATUS)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Unit Details</legend>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="add-spot" class="button button-primary">Add Spot</a>

    <div id="spot-details">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="hide">
                <tr>
                    <th>SL</th>
                    <th>Spot Name </th>
                    <th>Schedule Day </th>
                    <th>Schedule Time From</th>
                    <th>Schedule Time To </th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model != null && Model.Spots.Any())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Spots.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <tr data-id="@i">
                            <td> @(i + 1) </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model.Spots[i].SpotName
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Spots[i].SpotId, new { @class = "unit-spot-id" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Spots[i].Day,
                         MLMS.Common.UtilityHelper.EnumSelectListTextFieldSelected(MLMS.Common.UtilityHelper.ParseEnum<DayOfWeek>(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Spots[i].Day) ? "Friday" : Model.Spots[i].Day)),
                                                       "select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spots[i].Day)

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Spots[i].TimeFrom, new { @class = @"timepicker" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spots[i].TimeFrom)
                            </td>
                            <td class="timepicker">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Spots[i].TimeTo, new { @class = @"timepicker" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spots[i].TimeTo)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="button small button-danger" title="Remove" href="#" onclick="RemoveSpot(this); return false;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 60,
            minTime: '10',
            maxTime: '6:00pm',
            defaultTime: '11',
            startTime: '10:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Are you in debug mode? And you have not included required and dependent JavaScript and css in above code.

Comment: Have you also included `jquery`? And what if any errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: i have added jquery and and dependent js. @Amit , yes i am in debug mode. and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @star101- You have added but it is not showing added or referred in above code. Also you included min version of your js and css. Same is included or minification and bundling happens while project build? If so then you need debug version of js file and css?

Comment: all the references are in _layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin it looks better:
https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

Comment: Thats not an answer. i want to fix this

Comment: why you provide the same class for time control and the td,basically try to change the class on td